# Using an editable table with HighChart and having the chart refresh with change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I am building a prototype that uses [High charts - Data defined in a HTML table](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-parsed), I have applied an editable feature using jQuery so that the cells can be edited by the user. The question is:

How do I get the chart to update/refresh after a user edits a cell without using a database? I would like to use a button with an .click event listener to reload the chart from the edited table.

This is just a prototype so I have no need for an actual Ajax call or database connection. Basically I need user interaction with the table to reflect in the chart.

Here is a very simplified version:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            data: {
                table: document.getElementById('datatable')
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
            },
            yAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                title: {
                    text: 'Units'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.y +' '+ this.x.toLowerCase();
                }
            },
        });
    });
    $("#refresh").click(function() {
                var options = chart.options;
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
    </script>
    <script>
    $(function () {
        $("#datatable td").dblclick(function () {
            var OriginalContent = $(this).text();
            $(this).addClass("cellEditing");
            $(this).html("<input type='text' value='" +"' />");
            $(this).children().first().focus();
            $(this).children().first().keypress(function (e) {
                if (e.which == 13) {
                    var newContent = $(this).val();
                    $(this).parent().text(newContent);
                    $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
                }
            });
        $(this).children().first().blur(function(){
            $(this).parent().text(OriginalContent);
            $(this).parent().removeClass("cellEditing");
        });
        });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    <table id="datatable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Jane</th>
          <th>John</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Apples</th>
          <td>9</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Pears</th>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Plums</th>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>11</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Bananas</th>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Oranges</th>
          <td>2</td>
          <td>4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </body>


<button id="refresh">Refresh</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you were not defining your chart in:

```
$("#refresh").click(function() {
            var options = chart.options;
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
```

Try defining it before you call the new HighCharts code:

```
$("#refresh").click(function () {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    var options = chart.options;
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/zwN5w/).

Also note you have some invalid syntax in the tooltip as well as some dangling commas.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much Chad. If your ever in Hunt Valley MD I owe you a coffee. :)

Answer (score 2):

wergeld is correct.
You may try [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RYRyx/2/) which just updates the series data and refreshes the chart afterwards.

This will not recreate the chart from scratch, but rather only update it.
It's a bit more code, but depending on your usecase this might be useful.

here is the code in question:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
    // [...]
    series : [{ id: 'series1' }, { id: 'series2' }]
});

$("#refresh").click(function() {

    var complete = function(options) {
        // get the two HC-series objects
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        var series1 = chart.get('series1');
        var series2 = chart.get('series2');

        // set new data
        series1.setData(options.series[0].data, false);
        series2.setData(options.series[1].data, false);

        // and redraw chart
        chart.redraw();
    };

    // call the data parser of HC
    Highcharts.data({
        table : document.getElementById('datatable'),
        complete : complete
    });
});
```

Comment: hagbard this works nicely too, it doesn't require the redraw which is nice