# Generate chart from html table : JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, charts, highcharts, html-table

I want to add the data to the table manually and then generate the chart, can anyone see where I am going wrong?.

I have looked at other jQuery charts such as jqplot and Google charts, but they don't have what I am after.

My current system = http://jsfiddle.net/vr7L3/

Code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/theme1.min.css" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <meta charset="utf-8">



    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqm/demos/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />


    <script src="jqm/demos/js/jquery.js">
    </script>

    <script src="jqm/demos/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js">
    </script>

  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#theform').submit(function(){

        // make remove button and event
        var but = $('<button>remove</button>').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().parent().remove();
        });
        // make button td
        var buttontd = $('<td></td>').append(but);

        // make row
        var tr = $('<tr><td>'+$('#1').val()+'</td><td>'+$('#2').val()+'</td><td>'+$('#3').val()+'</td></tr>').append(buttontd);

        // add row to table
        $('#datatable').append(tr);

        // return false so form is not submitted
        return false;
    });
});


    $(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        data: {
            table: document.getElementById('datatable')
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            title: {
                text: 'Units'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    this.point.y +' '+ this.point.name.toLowerCase();
            }
        }
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
      <form id="theform">
    input something<input id="1" type="text"/><br/>
    input something<input id="2" type="text"/><br/>
    input something<input id="3" type="text"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


<table id="datatable">
        <tr>
        <th>heading 1</th>
        <th>heading 2</th>
        <th>heading 3</th>
    </tr>


    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you are doing anything to redraw the chart as the table is updated.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769735/using-an-editable-table-with-highchart-and-having-the-chart-refresh-with-change

Answer (score 1):

There were two problems.

1. You did not update the chart after drawing the table
2. Remove button made some confusion trying to parse it as a data point

So i have added the chart drawing part into another function and called to that for each table drawing. Removed the remove button so it wont make any more confusion for Highcharts. Please refer Highcharts documentation for updating datapoints without re-drawing the entire chart.

And also i added

```
e.preventDefault();
```

rather than returning a false to avoid form submission.

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vr7L3/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code does nothing to trigger highcharts to redraw the chart. Even if you call redraw, it won't work as you haven't told highcharts about the new data.

Rather than using data table, I suggest using the highcharts API call [addSeries](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries) to add the series each time the form is submitted. This avoids redrawing the entire chart each time.

Try something like this:

```
    $('#datatable').append(tr);
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    chart.addSeries({
            data:  [+$('#1').val(),+$('#2').val(),+$('#3').val()]
     });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dfpts/