# Plotting multiple series from HTML table generated by Ajax to Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I'm trying to display multiple data series into Highcharts's plot and I would like to get the data from an ajax self-calling function (In order to have an almost live charts without the redrawing of entire chart, but just the data updating) who refer to an external PHP file who gave me this table in output with the great advantage to have on the first row of the table the series name, and on the corresponding column the series values (I get the table filled with proper title from MySQL database):

```
 <table id='datatable'> 
    <tr> //First row representing series name
      <th>gap</th> 
      <th>best</th> 
      <th>last</th> 
      <th>rcp</th> 
      <th>tot</th> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> // Second row with corresponding series values for first point
      <td>16.011</td> 
      <td>527.238</td> 
      <td>527.238</td> 
      <td>527.238</td> 
      <td>527.238</td> 
    </tr> 
    <tr> // third row with corresponding series values for second point
      <td>18.433</td> 
      <td>519.296</td> 
      <td>519.296</td> 
      <td>523.267</td> 
      <td>1046.534</td> 
    </tr> 
</table>
```

Now in my Html page, I have a self calling Ajax function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/Highcharts/Highcharts-4.2.3/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script>
       var chart;
       var dataSource = 'TableForecast-03_testdontworking.php';
       var ChartHeight = window.innerHeight;
       var dataPoints = [];
       var index;
       function requestData()
       {
         $.ajax({url: dataSource, success: function(dataForMoreSeries) //dataForMoreSeries is the data you get from the request 
         {
           setTimeout(requestData, 2500);
         },
         cache: false
         });
       }

       $(document).ready(function() {
         //add our div for the chart
         $("#container").append("<div id=chart-Time style='width:100%''></div>");
         //StockChart
         //Chart
         chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
           chart: {
             height: ChartHeight,
             renderTo: 'chart-Time',
             defaultSeriesType: 'spline',

             events: {
               load: function() {
                 requestData();
               }
             },
           },
           title: {
             text: 'TIME'
           },
           xAxis: {
             type: 'datetime',
             title: {text: 'DAYTIME'},
           },
           yAxis: {
             title: {text: 'TIME'},
         },
         series: []
         }); //end chart       
       }); //end document.ready

      $(document).ready(function(){
          requestData();
      })
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want to achieve In this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nnm5yfLy/), but with the Ajax self-calling function. But, because i'm quite new to ajax and JS I have no ideas on how to proper feed the data from the table to the series, can you give me some suggestions?

Thanks,
Best regards

Comment: Why you cannot return the JSON from PHP, you save a time and parsing data. Morever the chart should be initialised in $.ajax() callback, to avoid problems with sync.

Comment: I was thinking about table becouse I see some example where highcharts seems to gets the series name from the table header (http://jsfiddle.net/nnm5yfLy/).

And this will be a great advantage on my code.

Comment: But then table require to be in the DOM. So JSON is more efficient and easy to use. Example of using json: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line

Comment: is it possible to retrieve the series name from a json?

Comment: Yes, you need to define the name field in the JSON. Example of JSON: {
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
        }

Comment: I just have to found the proper way to format the json in that way, from mysql. All the suggestions will be mouch apreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [`data`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#data) properties in highcharts. This gives you the ability to read data from an HTML table. Depending on your complexity you could be able to wire it directly in or you may need to loop over your table rows/columns to generate your series (you have not entirely explained your output so this is the most I can say at this point).
Now, to get the chart to draw on successful population of your table you could fire the chart builder code in the ajax call itself.

Here is a solution from hagbard for refreshing without redrawing entire chart object:

```
$("#refresh").click(function() {
    debugger;

    var complete = function(options) {
        // get the two HC-series objects
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        var series1 = chart.get('series1');
        var series2 = chart.get('series2');

        // set new data
        series1.setData(options.series[0].data, false);
        series2.setData(options.series[1].data, false);

        // and redraw chart
        chart.redraw();
    };

    // call the data parser of HC
    Highcharts.data({
        table : document.getElementById('datatable'),
        complete : complete
    });
});
```

This was taken as an expanded answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769735/using-an-editable-table-with-highchart-and-having-the-chart-refresh-with-change) question. You would need to move your refresh function call inside your ajax call to get new data in table.

Comment: I've edited the question with some more detailed info, and a jsfiddle example of what I would like to achieve.Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I can't fire the chart builder in the ajax call, because it will redraw all the charts after every timeout, I've just to feed the data in order to get de data updated every timeout, without redrawing the chart.

Thanks for the feedback, best regards.

Comment: I assume on initial load you can just read the table and build the chart. Then on data update (via Ajax or whatever) of contents of table you want to then update the series data in the chart, correct?

Comment: See hagbard's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769735/using-an-editable-table-with-highchart-and-having-the-chart-refresh-with-change. Does update without redrawing entire chart. You will have to call this "refresh" function in your ajax when you refresh your data.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused, because on every example there is the series assignation, who is what I want to avoid in my code, like in this jsfiddle, where the series names come from table headers: http://jsfiddle.net/nnm5yfLy/

Comment: How are you going to assign data to a chart without a series? The `Highcharts.data(...)` code at the end of the "refresh" function is what reads the table's columns to get the series and the rows to get the data points in each series. If you are worried about the hardcoded `var series1` section in the code then you have the ability to go in and list all the `series` items from the chart. Is your table you want to read from changing how many columns it has? If so then you would need to remove all series and add your new ones based on the columns available.

Comment: With data module, he can grab all the info from a table, or a proper formatted array. The only problem is how update the table and then the data in the plot, without redrawing every time the full plot.

Comment: @drypatrick, that is what this solution does. It re-draws the series - not the entire plot.

Comment: I understand your point, I was believing this I thought that with the given module, I could avoid this step.

Thank for explanation!!

Answer (score 1):

I've almost reach my objective, I can get the multi series displyed with proper names and values, extracted from the PHP file called by the *function getResult*.

The only problem is that I've got the full series redrewed on each time out, any suggestion on how to solve that?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script>

jQuery().ready(function(){
    setInterval("getResult()",1000);
});
function getResult(){   
    jQuery.post("table.php",function(data) {
        jQuery("#table").html(data);
    });


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            data: {
                table: document.getElementById('datatable')
            },
            chart: {
                type: 'line',
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Data extracted from a HTML table in the page'
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Units'
                }
            },
        });
    });
}
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    <div id="table" style="position: absolute; left: -9999em;"></div> //Style set to hide the table
    </body>
```

Comment: You can see if the data series you get in `getResult` = the current series elements already in the chart. If the are different then update the series. If not, then don't.